# Get Read and Writes per a duration

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to view the number of read and writes for a database or (tables in the database) in a day or week or month.

Currently, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT name AS 'Database Name'
    ,SUM(num_of_reads) AS 'Number of Read'
    ,SUM(num_of_writes) AS 'Number of Writes'
FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) I
    INNER JOIN sys.databases D
    ON I.database_id = d.database_id
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY 'Number of Read' DESC;
```

But this returns the total number of read and writes from the start.

Comment: Why not cache the results of that query at the end of each day?...and then your growth is the difference between two days.

Comment: If you do be sure to check whether the server has restarted since the last snapshot with `SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info`.